# Testing android room with Junit5 context

Tags: android, kotlin, android-room, junit4, junit5

I'm trying to migrate from Junit4 to Junit5 to make some parametrized test where room is involved. Currently for Junit4 it's working with @RunWith(AndroidJUnit4::class) class annotation and for Junit5 I can't find a equivalent, something like: @ExtendWith(AndroidJunit5::class)

I need it for the following part:

```
val context = ApplicationProvider.getApplicationContext<Context>()
        db = Room.inMemoryDatabaseBuilder(
            context, AppDatabase::class.java
        ).build()
```